When flagging a discussion on Discussion as spam, I get Page Not Found
I have been visiting Discussion several times in the last few days, mostly to view the newest discussions. When I found spam, I flagged it as spam. So far, so good; however, I assume that I have been lucky to make the flag that deletes the post. I have been redirected to the Page Not Found.
I can see deleted Q/A, but I understand that Discussions  is not yet full-fledged. I expect to be redirected to the list of discussions on Discussion or a message that the post was deleted.
Related

Can red flags on discussions nuke posts?


"My expectation is to be redirected to the list of discussions" that doesn't happen for questions either, why should there be a redirect on that?

What happens when you flag a question for spam that gets instantly deleted due to n flags and you don't have the rep to see deleted questions? does it to go to a 404? i'd consider both cases sub-par. A successful action should never leave you on a 404 page. At minimum it shouldn't reload the page, leaving you on the discussion/question you just flagged so you can click the breadcrumb back to the list.

@KevinB Only diamond and Discussions moderators can see deleted discussions. So when spam gets deleted that page is no longer accessible. If I remember correctly even for normal Q/A, if the user doesn't have 10K and makes an action that deletes the post then they will also get 404. I even think post can vanish with 404 even if you are merely reading it.

I mean, i'm aware of how it works for discussions, but thanks for the info on questions! yeah i think both cases are quite poor and due to be improved.

from a UX perspective I agree, but I have long ago given up thinking from a UX perspective on this site. It's a REST service with a UI (and some websockets thrown in for good measure).
